# Graphics card fan making noise in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, fan, noise

I've noticed that whenever i'm in Ubuntu the fan on my graphics card is running allot faster than when I am in Windows. I have a GTX 560 ti & i'm not sure if it is because the graphics card is lacking in its performance or if it is just Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and my graphics card is doing the exact same thing. I have a Radeon 6670. Maybe their is a driver issue. Go to the dash and type "additional drivers" and see if there are multiple drivers for your GPU. I have three drivers to choose from. Good luck!